# Alexa Skill: Get user location for "work"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I know how to get the device address from the Alexa app.

Now I need the addresses located in settings --> my locations. When I add a business address, I can use this address by saying "work".
I would like to use this address in my skill for work as well. How can I get it?

(Maybe the naming of settings is not 100% correct. I translated it myself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Amazon currently offers this to skill developers. Home & Work addresses are part of the user's Alexa account and would likely be accessed through the Customer Profile, but only name, email, and phone number seem to be available for skills to use according to their [Customer Profile API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html) docs.

Skills can only access an individual Alexa device's saved address through the [Device Address API](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Calling-Alexa-Service-APIs.html#deviceaddressserviceclient).

You can submit a feature request on their [Developer Voice and Vote](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote) site.

Comment: That's a pitty. I requested this feature here: https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/38198443-get-work-and-home-address

Thank you for your help, @Josh Broadhurst!